# Windows 10 - Disable warning notification about disabled firewall via GPO

Tags: group-policy, windows-10, windows-firewall, notification

Is there a way to disable the warning that is displayed in the notifications area, telling you that the Windows firewall is disabled?

Edit: We would specifically like to achieve this via group policy, not a manual process.

We disable the Domain firewall profile via GPO, which means Windows 10 machines constantly put warning notifications in the notification area about this. This generates user calls asking what the warning is about. We know it is disabled, so want to suppress the warning.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not possible to disable the firewall notifications alone, but since Windows 10 build 1607 it has been possible to disable all *Security and Maintenance Notifications* using

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Notifications\Settings\Windows.SystemToast.SecurityAndMaintenance\Enabled = 0 (DWORD)
```

UPDATE: According to Ladislav Louka, the required value has changed to `1` since build 1809.

Either add this registry key directly via Group Policy or create a custom ADMX template for it. See [Disabling Windows 10 Notifications via Group Policy](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/platforms_lync_cloud/2017/05/05/disabling-windows-10-action-center-notifications/) by Jeffrey Harness.

I think any of these notifications equally doesn't need attention of a single user, but these settings must be monitored & maintained by the administrators, instead. The scope of this modification seems ok.

Comment: That's a shame. I assume by the fact you suggest a custom ADMX template, this setting does not currently exist in the downloadable Windows 10 templates?

Comment: It seems so. I'd recommend creating the template suggested in the linked article if you have need for more of these settings. If you only need this one, simply add it as a direct registry update in your GPO.

Comment: This didn't work for me on Windows 10.  The registry setting was already set to 0.

Comment: Tried it, it did not work. (July 2019)

Comment: Tried, didnt work (windows 1903). There was no Windows.SystemToast.SecurityAndMaintenance param, i had to create it. Probably Microsoft moved setting to another place.

Comment: Try the answer below by Yassine Imounachen; it works for me (April 2020). (The answer above probably just doesn't work because the registry path changed -- though I don't know what the new one is, since I just use the "Group policy editor" program)

Comment: Follow up for anyone who tries this and it doesn't work. The DWORD value to disable notifications has for some reason been changed (I think in update 1809) to 1

Answer (score 13):

1. Click the Start button, type **Security and Maintenance**. (This should take you to `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Security and Maintenance` in the Control Panel.) You can also go directly to the control panel and get there that way.
2. Choose **Change Security and Maintenance settings**.
3. Uncheck **Network firewall**.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified that I would also like to do this via Group Policy (I will go back and edit my question accordingly)

Comment: I can see the "Report Problem - on" value, but I don't see a way to change it.  Windows 10 Pro 1903.

Comment: Found it under Windows Security => Firewall & network protection => Firewall Notification settings  => Manage notifications => Scroll down to the bottom.  Because that is obvious and not too buried.  Thanks Microsoft!

Comment: Tried it, it did not work. (July 2019.)

Comment: Try the answer below by Yassine Imounachen; it works for me (April 2020).

Comment: didn't work unfortunately

Answer (score 9):

Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Windows Defender Security Center -> Notifications -> Hide all notifications

Comment: Works! However, the setting appears to have been moved slightly. I found it here: Edit group policy (start menu search) -> Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Windows Security -> Notifications -> Hide all notifications

Comment: Doesn't work for me on Windows 1909. I still have the Windows Security - Action Needed icon in the tray.

Comment: tried all of the above, toast notification still popping up, then tried jedmon2 answer here https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/cexwbt/how_to_remove_windows_10_firewall_notification/ and now it's gone for good

Answer (score 9):

I have spent 3 days testing this on 2 machines. When the following is in place the notifications do not pop up for the the firewall. When I remove them they comeback. I also tested inserting this into the default user hive so that all new users logging in will get the the registry change.

This is for Windows 10 1809.

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PushNotifications]
"NoToastApplicationNotification"=dword:00000001
"NoToastApplicationNotificationOnLockScreen"=dword:00000001
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me on Windows 1909. I still have the Windows Security - Action Needed icon in the tray.